# What is the "nomkl" Python package used for?

Tags: python, conda, intel-mkl

I came across a script that installs the `nomkl` Python package:

```bash
conda install nomkl
```

What is the package `nomkl`? What it is used for?
I tried to search it but could not find any description of it on the web.

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/#uninstalling-mkl

Comment: The link seems to be dead? Any replacement?

Comment: @pallgeuer I put a wayback machine link in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66228570/570918).

Answer (score 11):

The `nomkl` package is not a Python package, but instead what the Conda documentation refers to as a [*mutex metapackage*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/packages.html#mutex-metapackages). Its sole purpose is to toggle the use of different build variant configurations in an environment. In this specific case, it controls whether other packages (such as NumPy) use Intel's MKL library for their BLAS implementation or something else (e.g., OpenBLAS). That is, many other packages link against the BLAS library during build and so there are equivalent versions of packages like NumPy that reference MKL or OpenBLAS symbols.

[The Anaconda documentation on MKL Optimizations](https://web.archive.org/web/20211011032929/https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/#uninstalling-mkl)<sup>**1**</sup> that @deceze dropped in the comments has details on `nomkl` specifically. However, since Anaconda 2023.03-0, there appears to have been an abandoning of `nomkl` in favor of directly including the specification `blas=*=openblas` in the `anaconda` package itself for the platforms, like **osx-arm64**, that are incompatible with MKL (see [Release Notes](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/release-notes/?highlight=nomkl#anaconda-2023-03-0-march-20-2023)). This is in effect identical, since this is the same constraint to `nomkl` defines.

---

<sub>**[1]:** The original link has died and now points at a Wayback Machine copy.</sub>